# Haskell token "#"

Tags: haskell

What does the `#` token mean and how is it used?

```
newtype IO a = IO (State# RealWorld -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))
```

I came across this [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Evaluation_order_and_state_tokens) and wonder where this type is actually defined or weather this is some syntax of a internal type that is ultimately defined in C?

Comment: This is not a token, it is part of the identifier, for example `State#`, `Int#`, etc. are types: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:State-35-

Comment: "internal type that is ultimately defined in C" is not accurate, but is at least morally correct in my eye. It is a lower-level implementation detail that one should not directly use. Pragmatically, don't mindlessly mess with `State# a` since that can break a lot of runtime invariants about IO and ST -- it's rather fragile. If you instead want to play with unboxed tuples to gain some performance, that should be safe (note that the optimizer might be already switching to those in many cases, so you might gain nothing...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#` marks the type as an [unboxed type](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#unboxed-types-and-primitive-operations). The `#` is conventional, but requires an extension (`MagicHash`) to make it valid syntax. Likewise, `(# ... #)` is the syntax for an unboxed tuple.